# Cognos Report Distribution Fails on Some Distribution Group Members

Tags: active-directory, cognos

**SOLVED:** We are currently running Cognos 11.1 and are unable to upgrade. I have a weird situation regarding members within an Active Directory Distribution Group.

One Distribution Group member recently changed her name which also resulted in an email address change. She was a member of this specific Distribution Group before her name change and remained in this specific Distribution Group after her name change.

Even though she remained in the Distribution Group, she has not received any reports since her name change. Is there a trick within Cognos that flushes a distribution group and re-establishes that distribution group with a report schedule?

**UPDATE:** It has to do with our 360 Admin Center not staying in synch with our local Exchange server. New "adds" are not a problem, everything synchs up properly. It appears "changes" are a bit trickier within the 360 Admin Center. Looks like we may have to issue a remove and add in order for it to work.

Comment: What happens if you (not Cognos) send an email to the distribution group?

Comment: It works fine. Everyone in the group receives the email.